# Is there any way to solve this optimization problem better than exhaustive search?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, maxima-minima, non-convex-optimization

Here is the optimization problem:

For the function

$$ f(x_1,x_2;a_0,b_0)=\\\small\cases{\frac{1}{2}\left[x_1+x_2-x_1x_2+\left(\frac{-1+b_0(1-a_0)}{a_0}x_1+1\right)\left(\frac{-1+b_0(1-a_0)}{a_0}x_2+1\right)\right],\quad 0 \leq x_1\leq a_0,\, 0 \leq x_2\leq a_0\\ \frac{1}{2}\left[x_1+x_2-x_1x_2+\left(\frac{-1+b_0(1-a_0)}{a_0}x_1+1\right)b_0(-x_2+1)\right],\quad\quad\,\,\,\,\,\quad 0 \leq x_1\leq a_0,\, a_0 \leq x_2\leq 1\\ \frac{1}{2}\left[x_1+x_2-x_1x_2+b_0(-x_1+1)\left(\frac{-1+b_0(1-a_0)}{a_0}x_2+1\right)\right],\quad\quad\,\,\,\,\quad a_0 \leq x_1\leq 1,\, 0 \leq x_2\leq a_0\\ \frac{1}{2}\left[x_1+x_2-x_1x_2+b_0(-x_1+1)b_0(-x_2+1)\right],\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad a_0 \leq x_1\leq 1,\, a_0 \leq x_2\leq 1}$$

and

$$f(x_1=x_2;a_0,b_0)=\cases{\frac{1}{2}\left[2x_1-{x_1}^2+\left(1+\frac{x_1(1+b_0(1-a_0))}{a_0}\right)^2\right],\quad 0 \leq x_1 \leq a_0\\\frac{1}{2}\left[2x_1+b_0^2(1-x_1)^2-x_1^2\right],\quad\quad\quad\quad\,\quad a_0 \leq x_1 \leq 1}$$

We have:

> $$\max_{a_0,b_0\in[0,1]}\left[\min_{{x_1=x_2\in[0,1]}}f(x_1,x_2;a_0,b_0) -\min_{{x_1,x_2\in[0,1]}}f(x_1,x_2;a_0,b_0)\right]$$

Is there a better way than brute force search? If yes, which method suits best? I mean to have less computational complexity by the word "best".

**My Idea**: I am thinking that the outer maximization could be done exhaustively but the inner minimizations could be solved somehow analytically. I dont know how to automize the process.

For example for given $a_0$ and $b_0$, one can take the derivative and make it equal to zero and insert back in the original equation and find the minimims. The problem is that I dont know if taking derivative finds me minimum or maximum? Any ideas?

Comment: For the inner minimizations, you can consider corner, kink/discontinuity points, and stationary points as candidates for minima for a given $(a_0,b_0)$.

Comment: @madnessweasley how to automize it for example in Mathematica?

Comment: A computationally attractive (but tedious) way would be to manually compute the derivatives and set them to zero to get at stationary points. For example, consider your $f(x_1 = x_2;a_0,b_0)$ function. You need to consider $x_1 = 0$, $x_1 = a_0$, $x_1 = 1$, and any points $x_1$ such that $f^{'}(x_1;a_0,b_0) = 0$ (to find the last set of points, you can manually differentiate each piece of the definition and solve for $x_1$ in terms of $a_0,b_0$. Of course, you can do better with second-derivative information).

Comment: @madnessweasley no second derivative information. The function is bi-linear. I still dont know how to let mathematica do it automatically. Otherwise this is a 4 dimensional optimization problem.